# Is it possible to 'import' part of a namespace (a module) into the current scope?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have one module called functionalUtilities which contains a number of utility functions.  An abbreviated version looks something like this:

```
MYAPP.functionalUtilities = (function() {
function map(func, array) {
  var len = array.length;
  var result = new Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    result[i] = func(array[i]);
  return result;
}
return {
    map:map,
};
})();
```

I then have a second module which contains core code:

```
MYAPP.main = (function() {

//Dependencies
var f = MYAPP.functiionalUtilities;

//Do stuff using dependencies
f.map(...)

})()
```

It seems messy and annoying having to remember to type `f.map` each time I want to use `map`.  Of course, in the dependencies, I could go though each of my functionalUtilities typing:

```
var map = f.map,
forEach = f.forEach,
```

etc.

but I wondered whether there is a better way of doing this?  A lot of articles on namespacing that I've read mention aliasing, but don't suggest a way to sort of 'import all of the contents of an object into scope'.

Thanks very much for any help,

Robin

[edit]  Just to clarify, I would like to use my functional utilities (`map` etc) within `MYAPP.main` without having to preface them every time with `f.`

This is possible by going through each function in `MYAPP.functionalUtilities` and assigning to a locally scoped variable within `MYAPP.main`.  But the amount of code this requires doesn't justify the benefit, and it's not a general solution.

Comment: I think manually defining local variables with `var map = f.map` is the way to go. You probably won't find any way of "importing" object properties automatically as local variables.

Comment: `with` can do that (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), but usage is forbidden in strict mode (i.e. its usage is deprecated overall).

Comment: Of course! I had forgotten 'with' due to the bad press it gets.  I guess I better read up on why it's not recommended to understand why it got deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment. There is no real way of automatically defining local variables out of object properties. The only thing that comes to my mind is using eval:

```
for (var i in MYAPP.functiionalUtilities) {
    eval("var " + i + " = MYAPP.functiionalUtilities[i];");
}
```

But I wouldn't use this method, since you could have object properties with strings as keys like this:

```
var obj = {
    "my prop": 1
};
```

"my prop" might be a valid key for an object property but it's not a valid identifier. So I suggest to just write `f.prop` or define your local variables manually with `var prop = f.prop`;

**EDIT**

As Felix Kling mentioned in the comment section, there is in fact another way of achieving this, using the with statement, which I don't really know much about except for that it is deprectated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a late answer - I feel like adding to basilikum's answer.

## 1) The `with` keyword could be useful here!

```
with(MYAPP.functiionalUtilities) {

    map(console.log, [ 'this', 'sorta', 'works', 'quite', 'nicely!' ]);

    // Directly reference any properties within MYAPP.functiionalUtilities here!!

};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

The `with` keyword is, in some ways, intended for exactly this situation. It should, of course, be noted that the mozilla developer link discourages use of `with`, and `with` is also forbidden in strict mode. Another issue is that the `with` statement causes its parameter to become the head of the scope chain, which means that it will always be checked first for all identifiers for all statements within the `with` block. This could be a performance hit.

## 2) An improvement to basilikum's answer

While a function call cannot add items to its parent-frame's scope, there is a way to avoid typing out a for-loop each time you wish to add a list of items to a namespace.

```
// First, define a multi-use function we can use each time
// This function returns a string that can be eval'd to import all properties.
var import = function(module) {
    var statements = [];
    for (var k in module) statements.push('var ' + i + ' = module["' + i + '"]');
    return statements.join(';');
};

// Now, each time a module needs to be imported, just eval the result of import
eval(import(MYAPP.functiionalUtilities));
map(console.log, [ 'this', 'works!' ]);
```

The idea here is to replace the need to write a for-loop with something like `eval(import(MYAPP.functiionalUtilities));`.

The danger here, as basilikum has stated, is that module properties need to be valid identifier names.